# Orika Mapping nested multi-occurrence elements

Tags: java, mapping, orika

I want map all persons (mens and womens) to the same PersonDto with Orika.

```
class Name {
   private String first;
   private String last;
   private String fullName;
   // getters/setters 
}

class Womens{
   private List<Name> names;
   // getters/setters 
}

class Mens{
   private List<Name> names;
   // getters/setters 
}

class Person {
   private Mens mens;
   private Womens womens;
   // getters/setters 
}

class PersonDto { 
  private List<Info> info;
  // getters/setters omitted
}

class Info { 
  private String notes;
  // getters/setters omitted
}
```

If I test with mens only, is it OK.

```
mapperFactory.classMap(Person.class, PersonDto.class)
       .field("mens.names{first}", "info[0].notes")
       .field("mens.names{last}", "info[1].notes")
       .field("mens.names{fullName}", "info[2].notes")
       .register();
```

If I test with womens only, is it OK,

```
mapperFactory.classMap(Person.class, PersonDto.class)
       .field("womens.names{first}", "info[0].notes")
       .field("womens.names{last}", "info[1].notes")
       .field("womens.names{fullName}", "info[2].notes")
       .register();
```

but if I test with mens and womens, is it KO. info array do not have the good size

```
mapperFactory.classMap(Person.class, PersonDto.class)
       .field("mens.names{first}", "info[0].notes")
       .field("mens.names{last}", "info[1].notes")
       .field("mens.names{fullName}", "info[2].notes")
       .field("womens.names{first}", "info[3].notes")
       .field("womens.names{last}", "info[4].notes")
       .field("womens.names{fullName}", "info[5].notes")
       .register();
```

Answer (score 0):

**I find a solution but is it not the best.** I you have a better respons, please post here you solution.

I split to two Infomaton class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "notes")
class InfoMen { 
    private String notes;
    // getters/setters omitted
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "notes")
class InfoWomen { 
    private String notes;
    // getters/setters omitted
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "persons")
class PersonDto { 
    private List<InfoMen> infoMen;
    private List<InfoWomen> infoWomen;

    @XmlElement(name = "notes")
    public List<InfoMen> getInfoMen() {
        return infoMen;
    }

    @XmlElement(name = "notes")
    public List<InfoWomen> getInfoWomen() {
        return infoWomen;
    }
    // setters omitted
}
```

My XML output is **OK but my PersonDto object contains two objects instand of one.**

```
<persons>
    <notes>
        <first>Petter</first>
        <last>Butter</last>
        <fullName>Petter Butter<fullName>
    </notes>
    <notes>
        <first>Wenddy</first>
        <last>Window</last>
        <fullName>Wenddy Window<fullName>
    </notes>
</persons>
```